# I am trying to export Json string into react and display in the console but I receive a comma error but cant figure out where to place it

Tags: reactjs

ProductRecords.js

```
export const productsJson =
  '[{"id":"1", "name":"Ford", "type":"Classic"},' 
  '{"id":"2", "name":"BMW", "type":"Saloon"},' 
  '{"id":"3", "name":"Tesla", "type":"Electric"}]';
```

Products.js -- this is where i am getting the error: 'Error in src/Products.js (8:72)
',' expected.'

```
import React from 'react';
import Product from './Product.js'
import { productsJson } from './ProductRecords';
const products = JSON.parse(productsJson);
function Products() {
const listProducts = products.map(
(product) => 
<Product id={product.id} name={product.name} type={product.type}/>));
return (
<div>
  <ul>
    {listProducts}
  </ul>
</div>
);
}

export default Products;
```

Product.js

```
import React from 'react';

function Product(props){
  return(
    <li key= {props.id}>{props.id}{props.name}{props.type}</li>
  );
}
export default Product;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import Products from './Products';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Products/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then index . js just renders app.

Comment: The error message is telling you where the problem is: `'Error in src/Products.js (8:72) ',' expected.'` Line 8, character 72.  You have an extra `)`.  Also, `productsJson` is not JSON, and it's not stringified JSON.  So that's something else to sort out.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'm pretty new to this so I am very grateful for your response! Could you give an example of Json if you could please?